# Is the existence of the world a miracle?

Tags: allah, theology, miracles, world

Miracles are used generally in theological/religious contexts; outside of them they're seen as either rationally explicable as signifiers of theological truths that are uncovered by hermeneutics of various kinds.

I want to see whether there are other valid ways at looking at miracles that might signify the presence of Allah.

For example - one question is why is there something rather than nothing. Physics starts from the supposition that some substance is there, and then establishes the laws that it obeys (generally conservation laws).

The explanation that the universe appeared out of nothing through some fluke quantum fluctuation doesn't explain anything, or more precisely it just pushes what is to be explained further back - that is the laws that guarantee a such a possible fluctuation. It's easily seen that a similar argument results in an infinite regression. Nor does Smolins offering of a eco-system of universes seeding each other offer a way out of this conundrum.

Hence the fundamental question remains - why something rather than nothing - does this count as a miracle?

For example, in Quranic hermenaeutics, the world is called th Greater Qur'an because it also signifies the presence of Allah (as Creater);

Is there anyway around this argument of infinite regression? I can't see that it is possible. In fact it has some contact with the antinomies of Kant who demonstrated there are question beyond the remit of reason. Which means that they must remain either unresolved or must be filled by faith of some kind.

A second possibility is the limits of causality that Hume identified, as well as al-Ghazali. Hume offered no resolution. Al-Ghazali offered Occasionalism - that is the world is sustained from moment to moment by the Allah. (In Koranic Hermeneutics its referred to the verse Al-Fatiha where Allah is called the Sustainer of the Worlds). Kant, of course offered a reasoned resolution by correlationism (which signifies the correlation between the human mind & the real). One might say, rather than God sustaining the illusion of the world as phenomena, it is the human mind - one has substituted Man for God - in at least as this position; but of course this still rather leaves noumena as undescribable and unexplained.

Comment: this is a nice question which your inquired, but to be honest, seemingly, this is pretty an extensive question, So I reckon that's why nobody replied it so far. (this is my opinion). Then, it is nicer if you make your question more limited. Good luck.

Comment: Since, honestly, according to my experience in this site (such as other sites), reader commonly not to refer to the questions which are extensive, and they commonly prefer to read the shorter questions. otherwise it is an interesting question which you inquired.

Answer (score 1):

Miracle is defined as:

> A miracle is an event not explicable by natural or scientific laws. Such an event may be attributed to a supernatural being (a deity), magic, a miracle worker, a saint or a religious leader.

Science hasn't discovered what was of the universe before the big bang so it can be called a miracle from that point of view.